# Anchoring a view to appear at position that was clicked?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a RecyclerView which contains many images. When an image is long clicked, I unhide an RelativeView (via `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`) to display a "preview" of the image in an ImageView until the long click is released at which point I hide the preview again. Currently, this is working as expected except that the preview always gets shown in the same spot on the screen.

Is there a way to anchor the preview to the position that the user clicked on? Ideally I'd like to have the bottom corner be aligned with the position at which the user is long clicking(or at least the bottom edge). This is what my preview looks like currently:

[image]

This is the RecyclerView and preview container layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Recyclerview -->
    <com.sometimestwo.moxie.MultiClickRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_zoomie_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Preview container that gets hidden/unhidden-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/hover_view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hover_view_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorBgBlackTint"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hover_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/hover_view_title"
            android:background="@color/colorBgBlackTint"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PopupWindow. In that you can set a particular view as anchor to show a window and inside the window you can show your preview.